# Indesign Overprint preview and guides not working

Tags: adobe-indesign, guides

I was working on something in indesign and I think I might have accidentally pressed something on my keyboard and toggled a different view. The background on the software changed colour and when I try to change to Overprint preview or to show the guides nothing changes on the document. Also previously I could see images that were off the page, but now I can't.

The image below is what it looks like now:

[image: indesign issue]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image: what i want]

Answer (score 1):

Simply looks like **Preview mode**... maybe you mistakenly tapped the `w` key.

`View > Screen Mode > Preview`

You can either just tap the `w` key again 
(without a text frame active), 
or choose `View > Screen Mode > Normal`